# Error: Invalid type specification for Optional attribute terraform

Tags: terraform, devops, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I have resource block to create Cloudfront origin request policy.
I have used a variable

```
variable "origin_cookies" {
  description = "Determines whether any cookies in viewer requests are included in the origin request key and automatically included in requests that CloudFront sends to the origin. Valid values are none, whitelist, all, allExcept."
  type = object({
    behavior = optional(string, "none")
    items    = optional(set(string), [])
  })
  default  = {}
}
```

and getting the below error from a few days back.

```
Error: Invalid type specification
on .terraform/modules/CfOriginReqPolicy/AWS/CloudfrontOriginReqPolicy/variables.tf line 30, in variable "origin_cookies":
30:     items    = optional(set(string), [])

Optional attribute modifier expects only one argument: the attribute type.
```

Previously the above code is working fine for last 6 months.

Comment: Have you changed terraform version ?

Comment: To add to the comment from @ChrisDoyle above, the `optional` modifier only started accepting a default value from v1.3, so if you've switched to an earlier version, it won't be expecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform assigns a null value to attributes and sub-objects.
you could try using the following.

```
items    = optional(set(string))
```